# decode RawH264IFrame to Bitmap or Image in C#

Tags: c#

first of all I'm sure the answer is already out there somehow, but I can't seem to find it. All I ever find is "use FFMPEG" but how?
I can't really find any description on which functions to use or even what functions are there at all? I'm using C# and I have a RawH264IFrame which I need to convert to Bitmap or Image.
Can anyone tell me where to find the right information?

Thank you!

Comment: The bitmap is BMP and definition is found at Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1):

[OpenH264Lib.NET](https://github.com/secile/OpenH264Lib.NET) is a C# wrapper for [OpenH264](https://github.com/cisco/openh264) encoder/decoder. It can also save images from the video stream.